# SQLite: Error while executing query: near "WITH"

Tags: sqlite

I need to change my Oracle query to SQLite.
It is some kind of calendar.

Oracle query, which works fine:

```
SELECT TRUNC(sysdate,'DD') - level AS d
FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 180
```

SQLite query, which I have written:

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
dates(day_date) AS (
SELECT date('now','-180 day')
UNION ALL 
SELECT day_date+1 
FROM dates WHERE day_date < date('now')
)
select * from dates;
```

It throws an error, when I am executing it.
*Error while executing query: near "WITH": syntax error*

What is wrong with my code? I used this page to check syntax: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common table expressions are not available before SQLite version [3.8.3](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_3.html).